# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object on insertion

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to save some information in my database with sql

```
    if(isset($_POST['hidden']))//check the checkbox
    $x=1;
else
    $x=0;
$pathh='../images/'.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$album=$_POST['album'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$order=$_POST['order'];
//echo $x.$album.$title.$order.$pathh;
$sql = "INSERT INTO `picture`(`url`, `album`, `title`, `order`, `hidden`) VALUES ('$pathh','$album','$title','$order','$x')";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

but when I run the page, it gives me the error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
```

I'm not very good at MySQL. What I did up there is that I copied the command of insertion from PHPMyAdmin and removed the `id` from it.

```
INSERT INTO `picture`(`id`, `url`, `album`, `title`, `order`, `hidden`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6])
```

What is the cause of this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Fetching on an `INSERT` would not work on a query that returns no results.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you very much, I removed the last sentence and the code now works like a charm :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error with the code is with the sentence

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Since Fetching on an `INSERT` would not work on a query that returns no results.